# How can I fix the 'network error' when sending an image post request to my Flask API using Axios in React Native?

Tags: react-native, image, post, axios

I want to send a post request to my api by sending an image in react-native but somehow, I'm getting **network error**. I wrote the same code in python for checking if my flask api is working properly or not and to my suprise it's working properly by using python code.

I'll provide both of the code, the code I've written in python and the code I've written in react-native for doing the same task. I'm using axios for requesting purposes.

React Native code:

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
 import { View, Text, Button, Alert, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
 import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';
 import axios from 'axios';

  export default function ImageView() {
    const [result, setResult] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const handleImageUpload = () => {
      const options = {
        mediaType: 'photo',
        quality: 1,
        includeBase64: false,
      };

      launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
        if (response.didCancel) {
          console.log('Image upload canceled');
        } else if (response.error) {
          Alert.alert('Error', response.error);
        } else {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', {
          uri: response.uri,
          type: response.type,
          name: response.fileName || 'image.jpg',
        });

        uploadImage(formData);
        }
       });
      };

    const uploadImage = (formData) => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    const apiURL = 'https://rrd.pythonanywhere.com';

    const fileData = new FormData();
    fileData.append('file', {
      uri: formData.uri,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: 'image.jpg',
    });

    axios
      .post(apiURL, fileData)
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        setResult(`${data.plant} - ${data.condition}`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
        console.log(error)
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
      };

      return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, color: 'black' }}>Image Upload</Text>
      <Button title="Capture or Upload Image" onPress={handleImageUpload} />
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
      ) : result !== '' ? (
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, color: 'black' }}>Result:</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: 'black' }}>{result}</Text>
        </View>
      ) : null}
      </View>
     );
    }
```

Python code:

```
import requests

api_url = 'https://rrd.pythonanywhere.com'
image_path = './test_images/0005_0008.jpg'
files = {'file': open(image_path, 'rb')}
response = requests.post(api_url, files=files)

if response.status_code == 200:
    
    data = response.json()
    print(f"Plant: {data['plant']}")
    print(f"Condition: {data['condition']}")
else:
    
    print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
```

I'll be glad if anyone let me solve this error.

I tried simple react request then switch to axios HTTP request but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I've spend a lot researching the error and I found out that the  `launchImageLibrary(options, (response)` , `repsonse` have an array of data when I upload an image from the gallery. Before realising that when I console log, uri, type and name, the answer I got is undefined. so what I did is in the following way:

```js
 const handleImagePickerResponse = (response) => {
    console.log('Image Picker Response:', response);
  
    if (response.didCancel) {
      console.log('Image upload canceled');
    } else if (response.error) {
      Alert.alert('Error', response.error);
    } else {
      const { uri, type, fileName } = response.assets[0];
      console.log("uri: ", uri);
      console.log("type", type);
      console.log("name:", fileName);
  
      if (uri) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', {
          uri,
          type,
          name: fileName || 'image.jpg',
        });
  
        setSelectedImageSource(uri);
        uploadImage(formData);
      }
    }
  };
```

This solves the error for me.